# Atribuir ID no momento da criação

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Galera, estou começando com Rails e fiquei com uma dúvida.

Preciso atribuir a ID de um "pai" no momento de criar seus "filhos". Por exemplo, Um Blog has_many Posts.

No momento que clicar no botão criar post o ID do Blog deve ser passado.
localhost:3000/blog/new_post/1 esse 1 seria o ID do blog.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que para seu caso você possa usar o conceito de `Nested Resources`.

Basicamente em seu `routes.rb` você irá fazer algo como:

```
resources :blogs do 
  resources :posts
end
```

Isso criará rotas como:

```
blog_posts GET    /blogs/:blog_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                        POST   /blogs/:blog_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_blog_post GET    /blogs/:blog_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_blog_post GET    /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     blog_post GET    /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                        PATCH  /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                        PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                        DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/posts/:id(.:format)
```

Assim você sempre terá o ID de blog como referência em suas contas.

**Atenção** observer que os `helpers` de `urls` também irão sofrer alteração, `post_path` para `blog_post_path` por exemplo sempre passando a referência de blog como `blog_post_path(@blog)`.